# how to add 'add to desktop' button on web app like in chrome menu

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

If user visit on my progressive web app and he don't know about chrome's add to desktop button on chrome menu so how can i tell him to install, is there any solution? like display button on web app, because if user visits "twice, over two separate days during the course of two weeks" then app install banner appears, so is it possible that when user visit first time then app install banner appears?

Answer (score 1):

Now this feature is not enable by default yet. You should force this banner in DevTools or enable in flag://. Normally banner will show at fist visit if enabled